# ASP.NET Core Angular app fails to run on Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx and Systemd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core Angular application targeting dotnet 1.1.0.

I installed Nginx on my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 and configured the nginx confog file as follows:

```
server {
listen 80;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

and myapp.services file as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sample application.

[Service]

Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/var/myappfolder
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/myappfolder/myapp.dll
#User=web

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tested this set up with a simple sample app and it worked fine. However as soon as I deploy my proper app to /var/myappfolder and configure

```
systemclt start mywebsite
systemclt daemon_reload
```

and then check

```
systemclt status mywebsite
```

I get this error:

> jtrade.service - Sample application.    Loaded: loaded
> (/lib/systemd/system/jtrade.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: failed (Result: signal) since Wed 2017-08-30 18:08:08 UTC; 9s
> ago   Process: 4640 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/jtrade/jtradep.dll
> (code=killed, signal=ABRT)  Main PID: 4640 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
>
> Aug 30 18:08:08 localhost dotnet[4640]:    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.NuGetCacheSentinel.get_NuGetCachePath()
>
> Aug 30 18:08:08 localhost dotnet[4640]:    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.NuGetCacheSentinel.Exists()
>
> Aug 30 18:08:08 localhost dotnet[4640]:    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.DotnetFirstTimeUseConfigurer.ShouldPrimeNugetCache()
>
> Aug 30 18:08:08 localhost dotnet[4640]:    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.DotnetFirstTimeUseConfigurer.Configure()
>
> Aug 30 18:08:08 localhost dotnet[4640]:    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ConfigureDotNetForFirstTimeUse(INuGetCacheSentinel
> nugetCacheSentinel)
>
> Aug 30 18:08:08 localhost dotnet[4640]:    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry
> telemetryClient)
>
> Aug 30 18:08:08 localhost dotnet[4640]:    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
>
> Aug 30 18:08:08 localhost systemd[1]: jtrade.service: Main process
> exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
>
> Aug 30 18:08:08 localhost systemd[1]: jtrade.service: Unit entered
> failed state.
>
> Aug 30 18:08:08 localhost systemd[1]: jtrade.service: Failed with
> result 'signal'.

So I dived deeper into debugging this error with `journalctl -u myappname` and got some more useful info:

> Started Sample application..
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]: Unhandled Exception:
> System.InvalidOperationException: Required environment variable 'HOME'
> is not set. Try setting 'HOME' and running the operation again.
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> NuGet.Common.NuGetEnvironment.GetValueOrThrowMissingEnvVar(Func`1
> getValue, String name)
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> NuGet.Common.NuGetEnvironment.GetHome() Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost
> dotnet[10290]:    at
> NuGet.Common.NuGetEnvironment.<>c.<.cctor>b__12_0()
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]: --- End of stack trace from
> previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> NuGet.Common.NuGetEnvironment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder folder)
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> NuGet.Common.NuGetEnvironment.GetFolderPath(NuGetFolderPath folder)
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> NuGet.Configuration.SettingsUtility.GetGlobalPackagesFolder(ISettings
> settings)
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> NuGet.Configuration.NuGetPathContext.Create(ISettings settings)
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.NuGetCacheSentinel.get_NuGetCachePath()
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.NuGetCacheSentinel.Exists()
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.DotnetFirstTimeUseConfigurer.ShouldPrimeNugetCache()
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.DotnetFirstTimeUseConfigurer.Configure()
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ConfigureDotNetForFirstTimeUse(INuGetCacheSentinel
> nugetCacheSentinel)
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry
> telemetryClient)
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost dotnet[10290]:    at
> Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost systemd[1]: jtrade.service: Main process
> exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost systemd[1]: jtrade.service: Unit entered
> failed state.
>
> Aug 31 05:13:34 localhost systemd[1]: jtrade.service: Failed with
> result 'signal'.

From here if I run to see my environment variables with printenv, I find that HOME= /root

Maybe it should be set to something else?

Comment: Just a quick note, after I publish the app using dotnet publish on my local machine I check the myapp.dll and run it with dotnet myapp.dll and it runs fine.

Comment: Also, on the server if I simply run the app with dotnet myapp.dll it also runs fine. So it is something to do with systemd configs I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I just wrote 
Environment=HOME=/root
in the .service file and everything started working